# Why is a certain sentence repeated so many times in Parsha of Tzav

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

In Parshas Tzav, the Pasuk, וידבר ה׳ אל משה לאמר: is repeated many times… sometimes only a few sentences apart. We know that not one extra letter is written in the Torah. The question is why is this phrase repeated so many times?

Comment: This verse shows up all over the Torah. Is it particularly more common here?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Menachem! Out of all the פרשיות השבוע, Tzav does have six instances of this pasuk which ties it for second-most in the Torah with Naso (a very long parsha).  You might also ask the same for Emor which has eleven instances and is only roughly 25% longer than Tzav.  Of general interest to me is why some sections  of the Chumash begin with ויאמר and some begin with וידבר.